# Kubernetes namespace post and pre delete hooks

Tags: kubernetes, automation, webhooks

Is there a way to trigger an external API whenever a Kubernetes namespace is getting deleted. Are there any post and pre hooks for namespace deletion/creation.

Or are there any way to handle it using any other Kubernetes resource except Pod

Comment: I checked. if there is any events coming out from Kubernetes get the event, which also doesn't have any specific event on the deletion of the namespace.

Comment: I think you must create an operator, allow it to look for `namespace` resource, and create the endpoint request.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a [webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) to perform any task/operation that you want to do. When a a request to delete a namespace comes to kubernetes API server the webhook will be called by kubernetes API server automatically. A webhook is an http/https endpoint to a running piece of software which could be running in the Kubernetes cluster itself or somewhere else. A webhook need to be registered to Kubernetes API server to be able receive the request from the API server.